# How to calculate sum of a column based on two conditions in python

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

Hi I am new in python and I have a dataset like this:

[image]

I need to create two columns Female and Male which will have the total births of female and male respectively based on decade. So my result dataframe should be like this:

[image]

I tried using groupby but that returns something like this:

dataset.groupby(['decade','gender'])['births'].sum()

[image]

But I need F and M as two additional columns.

Could you please advice me what I should do? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

decade = [1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1960, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980]
gender = ['F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M']
births = [4192, 4198, 4710, 4850, 4646, 5092, 4800, 4934, 4126, 4324, 4758, 5076, 5070, 5296, 4798, 5096]

dataset = pd.DataFrame({
    'decade': decade,
    'gender': gender,
    'births' : births
})
```

Try this:

```
df = dataset.groupby(['gender', 'decade'])['births'].sum()
df = df.unstack(level=0)
```

[image]